# Exclude lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, code

I want to save paper when I print my LaTeX file. That's why I want to hide all my code, inserted wtih `lstinputlisting{}`

I already know how to exclude tables and images or math but the `lstinputlisting{}` is a problem.

Hope someone can help me

```
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{figure}
\let\endfigure\relax
\excludecomment{table}
\let\endtable\relax
\excludecomment{align*}
\let\endalign\relax
\excludecomment{lstlisting}
\let\endlstlisting\relax
```

*edit:* added lstlisting

Answer (score 6):

`\lstinputlisting` can be redefined via `\renewcommand`. The macro has one optional and one mandatory argument:

```
% ignore \lstinputlisting
\renewcommand*{\lstinputlisting}[2][]{}
```

Environment `lstlisting` can be excluded as the other environments:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{lstlisting}
```